# using both setOnItemClickListener and setOnItemLongClickListener both listener fired same time or works same time.Why

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In `ListView` I am using both `setOnItemClickListener()` and `setOnItemLongClickListener()`. When I click on an item it works fine but when I long-click on an item sometimes both listeners are fired at same time or work at same time. Why?

```
/**
* on click of list view item show the run time webview.
*/
mListViewStar.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
        isHome = true;
        Animation translate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Home.this,
                R.anim.tran_right);
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRelativeLayout.startAnimation(translate1);
        // mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "",
                "Loading...");
        addWebView(mArrayListJBSelectedUrls.get(arg2)
            .getStrSelectedWebsiteUrl().toString(), arg2);
    }
});
/**
* on long press delete item from list view
*/
mListViewStar.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
        position = arg2;
        AlertDialog.Builder mAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
        mAlert.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert));
        mAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        mAlert.setMessage(getString(R.string.delete_item_dialog));
        mAlert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    mDataBaseMethod.open();
                    Log.i("Delete", ""
                        + mArrayListJBSelectedUrls
                        .get(position)
                        .getStrSelectedUrlId());
                    mDataBaseMethod
                        .deleteWebSites(mArrayListJBSelectedUrls
                        .get(position)
                        .getStrSelectedUrlId()
                        .toString());
                    mArrayListJBSelectedUrls.remove(position);
                    starBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mDataBaseMethod.close();
                }
        });
        mAlert.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = mAlert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This should not happen, can you post some of your code? If an event is passed to onItemLongClickListener it should not trigger the standard onItemClickListener.

Answer (score 28):

add return true on onItemLongClick

Comment: thanks onItemLongClick return true then onItemClick and long both listener not working together...!!!

Answer (score 1):

setOnClickListener activates first as axpected, problem starts when you want both actions together , to avoid this you need to **return true**; on OnItemLongClickListener.

```
lv_frag_three.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //Groups clickedObj = (Groups) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                // your actions
            }
        });
});

  lv_frag_three.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

try fix

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3)
```

and

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3)
```

to

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,final View arg1,final int arg2,
          final long arg3)

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,final View arg1,
               final int arg2,final long arg3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You must return `false` on function `onItemLongClick`